# Pandas regex upcase after colon and space

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# Source data
df = pd.DataFrame( data={'A': ['abc: aaa 123: 111', 'edf: 111', 'ghi: a11 324: aaa', 'jkm: bn2 jsk: 1f4']})


df['A'] = df['A'].re.sub("(^|[:])\s*([a-zA-Z])", lambda p: p.group(0).upper(), s)
```

Result:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 're'

I would like to upcase all letters after colon and space ": "

```
df = pd.DataFrame( data={'A': ['abc: Aaa 123: 111', 'edf: 111', 'ghi: A11 324: Aaa', 'jkm: Bn2 jsk: 1f4']})
```

Comment: After the first colon or only after the last?

Comment: Cells contain multiple ": " so after all colon spaces

Comment: I would like to uppercase only first letter not all. First character if it is letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['A'] = df.A.str.replace(r':\s+[a-zA-Z]', lambda p: p.group(0).upper())

# output

                   A
0  abc: Aaa 123: 111
1           edf: 111
2  ghi: A11 324: Aaa
3  jkm: Bn2 jsk: 1f4
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working.

Comment: Glad it worked! Please mark as accepted if this solves the problem.